# How do I use Any() instead of RemoveAll() to exclude list items?

Tags: c#, list, linq, any, removeall

`ListWithAllItems` contains two type of items: ones I want select, and ones that I don't.

`listForExcluding` contains item that I should to exclude:

```
List<string> listForExcluding = ...;
```

So I do it in two strings:

```
List<string> x = ListWithAllItems.ToList();

x.RemoveAll(p => listForExcluding.Any(itemForExclude => itemForExclude == p));
```

How do I use `Any()` instead of `RemoveAll()` to get this query with one line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Any` doesn't make sense here, just use `Except`:

```
var filtered = ListWithAllItems.Except(listForExcluding);
```

`ToList` if you actually need a list at the end, otherwise don't realize IEnumerables for no reason (causes an extra enumeration).

If you really want the `RemoveAll` version for some reason, use `Contains` (this is also how to do it using `Where`):

```
x.RemoveAll(p => listForExcluding.Contains(p));
```

There's a number of other valid lines... but seriously just go with `Except`